The relationship between Tun/Tap and Tcp/Ip stack when Tun/Tap connect to a bridge
I know theres program such like OpenVPN can use tun to interact with Tcp/Ip stack. And I know we can use Tun/Tap with bridge to do things like vm networking.
But I wondering when a Tun/Tap connects to a bridge, And what happend to it. Will it still receiving the data from Tcp/Ip stack?
And how will the Tun/Tap knows where the packet from and where the data will send to (bridge or stack).
Or should I just prevent using tun/tap in normal request when I am connecting it to beidge?
I searched A lot and I didnt find any answer about this.

TAP interfaces, when bridged, behave exactly the same way as any other Ethernet-like interface when bridged: Ethernet frames "arriving" through the interface (whether from the Cat5 cable or from the OpenVPN process) will enter the bridge as normal, and the bridge will forward them either to the host OS or through some other bridge port according to destination MAC address.
So if the incoming frames have the host's MAC as their destination MAC, they'll eventually (through the bridge) reach the host's TCP/IP stack.
(In short, the only difference is that a TAP interface has a software process instead of a real Ethernet cable.)
TUN interfaces cannot be put in a bridge, as they don't have L2 addressing (and that's literally what makes them different from TAP interfaces).

You mean the tap will work like a ethernet. And I wonder the destination mac should be bridges mac or tap's mac to the tcp/ip stack?

The host's MAC address is the one that's set on the bridge interface, while the bridged tap interface becomes a 'dumb' port. Again, same as with any other Ethernet-like interface that is bridged.
